# Creating Azure Functions using .NET 5 and Docker

Tags: .net, azure, docker, .net-core, azure-functions

There is some Azure Function that uses an Isolated Model, running as [an out-of-process language worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker) that is separate from the Azure Functions runtime. Because Azure Functions runtime doesn't support .NET5 yet.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm looking for a way how to deploy .NET func as a Docker container.
[image]

```
func init LocalFunctionsProject --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated --docker
```

For .NET 3.1 I had Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

How to containerize .NET5 func? Is it even possible? Any workarounds? I've not found a solution yet. Please suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so there are two things going on:

1. There is still a dependency on the .NET 3.1 Core SDK even in .NET 5.0 Functions projects, which [seems to be "by design."](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/297)
2. The Dockerfile that we generate for a project with --worker-runtime = dotnet-isolated --docker [is missing a key line to add the reference to .NET Core 3.1.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/519#issuecomment-869852227)

To fix this, add the following lines after the first FROM statement in the Dockerfile:

```
# Build requires 3.1 SDK
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS installer-env
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet

COPY ./LocalFunctionsProject/ /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:3.0-dotnet-isolated5.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal) will be updated soon